# Jenkins Error: Publish JUnit Test result report failed

Tags: ios, iphone, unit-testing, jenkins, junit

I am trying to setup jenkins for my IOS app. The app is building successfully. But when I configure JUnit and give value **test-reports/*.xml** in Test report XMLs(Publish JUnit test result report) I get the following error

Recording test results
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: **No test report files were found**. Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE

I have also added a xml file myself (**test-report.xml**) and give its path in Test report XMLs. Now when I build I get following error.

Recording test results
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: T**est reports were found but none of them are new**. Did tests run? 
For example, /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test_jenkins/test-report.xml is 4 hr 2 min old

Finished: FAILURE

Can you please help me in setting up JUnit.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find an answer ?